# How to create new edit forms in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Right now Devise generated edit.html.erb, which is great for editing essential info. However, I want to generate a new edit page, similar to edit.html.erb, but there, users will be able to edit other information about themselves.. I don't want to put everything on edit.html.erb because of UI.

So far I only added new columns to users table for a new edit page that I'm going to create.

Right now these are my routes:

```
 devise_for :users, class_name: 'FormUser', :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'registrations' }


  root 'setup#index'
  get '/setup' => 'setup#index'
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'setup#index'
```

And this is my registration_controller.rb:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    if resource.encrypted_password.blank? # || params[:password].blank?
      resource.email = params[:email] if params[:email]
      if !params[:password].blank? && params[:password] == params[:password_confirmation]
        logger.info "Updating password"
        resource.password = params[:password]
        resource.save
      end
      if resource.valid?
        resource.update_without_password(params)
      end
    else
      resource.update_with_password(params)
    end
  end
end
```

So I created a new controller with views but I have no idea what to put now in the routes.
Name of the new controller is styles_controller.rb and and views are fits.html.erb..

Comment: What do you mean by "connect" existing controller?

Answer (score 0):

This script will generate controllers for you to override the behavior of Devise (but I highly recommend you do not do that):

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers

This shows you how to generate the view templates for you to override the default screens to login/etc.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

And this tutorial shows how to allow users to edit their profile without a password:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password